# Animated gauge chart using rAmCharts

Tags: javascript, r, amcharts

I am trying to implement a Gauge chart in R using package `rAmCharts` as shown in https://www.amcharts.com/demos/animated-gauge/

Below is my code

```
amAngularGaugeChart() %>%
    setAxis(topTextFontSize = 20,
            topTextYOffset = 70,
            axisColor = "#31d6ea",
            axisThickness = 1,
            endValue = 100,
            gridInside = true,
            inside = true,
            radius = "50%",
            valueInterval = 10,
            tickColor = "#67b7dc",
            startAngle = -90,
            endAngle = 90,
            unit = "%",
            bandOutlineAlpha = 0,
            bands = list(list(color = "#0080ff",
                              endValue = 100,
                              innerRadius = "105%",
                              radius = "170%",
                              gradientRatio =  c(0.5, 0, -0.5),
                              startValue =  0),
                         list(color = "#3cd3a3",
                              endValue = 0,
                              innerRadius = "105%",
                              radius = "170%",
                              gradientRatio = c(0.5, 0, -0.5),
                              startValue = 0))) %>%
    setArrows(alpha = 1,
                innerRadius = "35%",
                nailRadius = 0,
                radius = "170%")
```

However with above code, I am getting below error :

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘setAxis’ for signature ‘"AmChart", "missing"’
```

Any pointer on how to correctly implement **Animated Gauge chart** in R using `rAmCharts` would be highly appreciated.